# jQuery Folder Manager Plugins?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

Anyone know of a jQuery plugin that supports managing file folders? I already have the ability to upload files, now I'd like to give users the ability to organize files into folders?

Comment: You'll probably have to cook something up specific. Is there any current product out there that has this feature?

Comment: Does jQuery File Tree do the trick? http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery_file_tree

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery File Tree](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/) is a configurable, AJAX file browser plugin for jQuery. You can create a customized, fully-interactive file tree with as little as one line of JavaScript code.

[dnamique blog](http://www.dnamique.com/file-browser-for-ruby-on-rails/) has a rails connector for this plugin and **sources** and **demo** about it.