# Rails implementation of a database-based file system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filesystems

Because "file system" and "rails" are such common topics both together and separate I fail to find any [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) open source app that implements a file system in the database. I would like to use such an application as a starting point or template.

I've already been able to implement the `User` and the `Directory` models (using [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) for the latter), and I'm on my way for the `File` model (my app only requires one kind of file).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :directories, dependent: :destroy
  # ...
end # class User

class Directory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :parent_id
  has_ancestry
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :files, dependent: :destroy
  # ...
end # class Directory

# not actually implemented, yet
class File < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :directory
  # ...
end # class File
```

In views I'm using [jsTree](http://luban.danse.us/jazzclub/javascripts/jquery/jsTree/reference/_examples/1_datasources.html) to present the tree and a form to add/delete, edit, ... This will need to change into using [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) because redirecting back to same page does not preserve the expanded/collapsed state of the tree.

However I have this nagging feeling that I'm doing something that has already been done lots of times. Can you please provide links to such application(s) or give hints about implementing both the model part and the view part?

Comment: Do you just need to model the file system, or do you also need to store the file data in the database?

Comment: I'm also storing the content in the database. Right now I have a Directory model that has_many files, a File that belongs to Directory and stores generic information including a file_type and an file_index and one table for each type of file. Maybe because I'm a noob in Rails I did not find the STI or MTI suitable.

Comment: Can't you just use your system's file system? The implementation would be way easier, and I can't see much gain in using a database to simulate a file system.

Comment: Maybe one can use Rails to see the underlying file system in the server where the final application will be stored, I did not investigate that in any deep. This is a valid comment for the question as it is posted (I kept it general because I did not find general answers in my searches). In my particular case the data has relational connections that make sense to be implemented in a database, I think. https://github.com/TNick/equtree

Comment: @TNick, did you try to use core Directory and File classes for your task? I have the same problem with data storage, but my project has nearly 10 different file classes

Comment: @gaussblurinc my project is temporary parked. At that time I used (some form of) custom classes presented above. My use case was about tree-like data, with nodes that have a name and a collection of sub-nodes and/or leafs and leafs with some content in it, not actual files on the actual file system. Is it possible to use core Directory and File classes can be used in this set-up? I did not went on that road..

Comment: @TNick, well, no, core classes rely on file system items like files, files as directories, files as pipes and etc. sizes, access rights and so on. If you implement all files-related methods and also many others, you 'can' replace your content with this `file in folder` concept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Hints about implementing the **model** part

To get model to be organised as a tree structure the tecnique is know as [Nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) therefore a common name (helpful to googling etc. ) could be **"Activerecord nesting"** ;-)

Your choice about **Ancestry** is welcome but you can benefit having a look at projects (mix-in,plug-in,...) like:

- [awesome_nested_set](http://rubydoc.info/gems/awesome_nested_set/2.1.6/frames)

  - act_as_nested_set
  - [Better nested set](https://github.com/chris/better_nested_set)
- [act_as_a_tree](https://github.com/erdah/acts_as_tree)
- [Closure Tree](http://mceachen.github.io/closure_tree)
- [Arboreal](https://github.com/mdub/arboreal)

For the **file upload 'n store** part I would suggest , in addition to the already mentioned *Paperclip*, to look at [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) by itself provides a storage based on the *"fog"* gem (supports storing files with AWS, Google, Local and Rackspace ) but you can opt for database (e.g. sqlite) storage leveraging [carrierwave-activerecord](https://github.com/richardkmichael/carrierwave-activerecord)

### Hints about implementing the **view** part

About "views" you might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16657954/1657028) about [jQuery File Tree](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/) a configurable AJAX file browser plugin for jQuery and [**dnamique blog**](http://www.dnamique.com/file-browser-for-ruby-on-rails/) which has a rails connector for this plugin and **sources** and **demo** about it.

as an alternative, look at the implementation (sources) of the applications mentioned in next section.

### Links to such **applications**

Here some *"File manager"* of interest:

- [Boxroom](https://github.com/mischa78/boxroom)
- [Saphyra](https://github.com/spieker/saphira) (available as mountable engine)
- rails based CMS might have code of some interest

Comment: what part of rails based cms ( am I right that you mentioned active record here ?) could help in 'file manager' part? I have interest in ruby file managers field

Answer (score 3):

I think you're on the right track. Your `Directory` and `File` models look fine to me.

Your nagging feeling is partly correct. It's a common requirement to support uploading and storing files, but it's not that common to model and display an entire hierarchal directory structure.

You may want to reconsider actually storing the files in the database. This is usually a bad idea. Since files are such variable sizes, they can bloat your table and hurt performance. I recommend storing your files in Amazon S3. This is much more reliable and fast storage, and you can serve S3 urls directly to clients to reduce bandwidth and load on your own servers. You can use the [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem to handle file uploads and store the files either on disk or on S3.